# Setting up an XSLT Ingestion Crosswalk for MODS DSpace 4.2

Tags: dspace

I am new to DSpace and I want to set up an ingestion crosswalk for MODS.  Ultimately, I am trying to harvest OAI feeds with metadata records in a MODS format.  I followed the instructions from https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/XsltCrosswalk, but I am now stuck.

When I run: "sudo ./dspace dsrun  org.dspace.content.crosswalk.XSLTIngestionCrosswalk mods /home/dhenry/mods_example.xml"

I get the following error:
"Error, cannot find an IngestionCrosswalk plugin for: "mods""

Here are the relevant lines from dspace.cfg:

```
 # Configure table-driven MODS dissemination crosswalk
    #  (add lower-case name for OAI-PMH)
    crosswalk.mods.properties.MODS = crosswalks/mods.properties
    crosswalk.mods.properties.mods = crosswalks/mods.properties

    # Configure XSLT-driven submission crosswalk for MODS
    crosswalk.submission.MODS.stylesheet= crosswalks/mods-submission.xsl
```

......

```
   # Crosswalk Plugin Configuration:
    #   The purpose of Crosswalks is to translate an external metadata format   
    #   the DSpace Internal Metadata format (DIM) or the DSpace Database.
    #   Crosswalks are often used by one or more Packager plugins (see below).
    plugin.named.org.dspace.content.crosswalk.IngestionCrosswalk = \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.AIPDIMCrosswalk = DIM, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.AIPTechMDCrosswalk = AIP-TECHMD, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.PREMISCrosswalk = PREMIS, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.OREIngestionCrosswalk = ore, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.NullIngestionCrosswalk = NIL, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.OAIDCIngestionCrosswalk = dc, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.DIMIngestionCrosswalk = dim, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.METSRightsCrosswalk = METSRIGHTS, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.RoleCrosswalk = DSPACE-ROLES, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.ModsCrosswalk = MODS

    plugin.selfnamed.org.dspace.content.crosswalk.IngestionCrosswalk = \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.XSLTIngestionCrosswalk, \
      org.dspace.content.crosswalk.QDCCrosswalk
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to change 
crosswalk.submission.MODS.stylesheet= crosswalks/mods-submission.xsl
to 
crosswalk.submission.mods.stylesheet= crosswalks/mods-submission.xsl
and
 org.dspace.content.crosswalk.ModsCrosswalk = MODS
to
 org.dspace.content.crosswalk.ModsCrosswalk = mods

Comment: Thanks Adan,  Changing from "crosswalk.submission.MODS.stylesheet" to "crosswalk.submission.mods.stylesheet" is what worked.   But I had to remove the line "org.dspace.content.crosswalk.ModsCrosswalk = mods" to avoid a name collision in the XSLTIngestionCrosswalk.